# iOS Simulator "cannot be loaded in a restricted process"

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

Just running my iOS project in the iOS Simulator and then get this error:

> "dyld_sim: cannot be loaded in a restricted process"

Comment: Killed the sim & Xcode and retried? Tried another sim?

Comment: This is very unexpected. Can you file a bug with the output of `xcrun simctl diagnose` and `sudo sysdiagnose -q`? Did you modify your build configuration? Does a template project work?

Comment: I've opened Bug Report 51189518 with the requested logs.

Comment: I don't definitively have an answer for you, but this is what I discovered. My dyld_sim failure occurred while testing a debug build with an older Simulator version. It occurred at the same point where I have a thread sanitizer race-condition on the latest Simulator. Suspecting that possibly the threading race condition was generating a signal that was not being caught on the older Simulator, I switched to the release build, and the problem went away. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

[Kevin Packard's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47650438/ios-simulator-cannot-be-loaded-in-a-restricted-process#comment99431580_47650438) gave me an insight on how to work around this issue. So basically there are several options:

1. As Kevin said, you can simply switch to `Release` configuration which will turn off `Thread Sanitizer`.
   [image: Release configuration]

---

2. And yeah, the second option is to turn off `Thread Sanitizer` directly.
   [image: Thread Sanitizer]

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem came because I changed folder names and had to delete and re-add files in the process. In doing so, I deleted AppDelegate.swift and SceneDelegate.swift and forgot to add them back. After copying those files from another project and adding them into the one I was working on, everything was fixed.

[image: AppDelegate.swift and SceneDelegate.swift in project folder.]